# Laravel 7 API Resource showing only data that contains relationship

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

This my code stored in my API Controller:

```
return ApartmentResource::collection(Apartment::with(['sponsors'])->paginate(5));
```

It shows all `Apartments`, someone have the sponsor array empty, someone not.

How i can show only the Apartments that actually have sponsors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `has()` method

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
return ApartmentResource::collection(Apartment::has('sponsors')->with(['sponsors'])->paginate(5));
```

`with()` simply eager loads the sponsors: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

**use** `array_filter()`

**example:**

```
$result = array_filter($array);
```

array_filter() remove empty array elements from array.